# Procedural texture does not work

Tags: materials, procedural

I am using blender and rhino.
but today i realize that my obj date from rhino can not be rendered in blender with Procedural material. does someone know the reason? thanks!

[image]

left is the cube from blender, right is obj date imported from rhino.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16uiYZaY4Kmw9sKkrkY8pX4jlbEBlTFI4/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5):

The scale of your object is very small

[image: Scale of object]

you can apply the scale by pressing Ctrl+A and select "Scale" option.

[image]